# need help converting range of numbers to an average in R when the variable contains both range and one number

Tags: r, string

I am working on not structured data and want to make it one type data.
I have a column containing ranges and numbers at the same time

```
x <- c("0-7", "8", "12-15", "16", "20-23", "24-27", "28")
```

and want to get the average for only the range observations and the others leave the same

```
# "3.5" "8" "13.5" "16" "21.5" "25.5" "28"
```

it tried this code:

```
data$column = mean(range(lapply(strsplit(as.character(unique(data$column)),"-"), as.numeric)))
```

but I keep getting errors

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution :

```
s <- c("0-7", "8", "12-15", "16", "20-23", "24-27", "28")
sapply(strsplit(s, split = "-", fixed = TRUE), function(k) mean(as.numeric(k)))
```

Then you can convert back to character with `as.character`

Improved thanks to @nicola and @David Arenburg

Comment: (nitpick mode on) I'd just remove the curly brackets (`{`), since they are not needed and use `split="\\-"` just to outline the fact that `-` is a regex special character (even if it doesn't make much of a difference).

Comment: or add `fixed = TRUE` which will be both more efficient and make sure we are not talking regex here. Though the question here is, what happens if there are negative numbers in the vector.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works for me and savemuch of my time !

Answer (score 0):

Tried to do that trough `eval`. Sure somebody else got better experience with that, would be glad to get some useful info.

```
sapply(parse(, , gsub("(\\d+)\\-+(\\d+)", "mean(\\1:\\2)", x)), eval)
# [1]  3.5  8.0 13.5 16.0 21.5 25.5 28.0
```

Comment: I am not good at using reg ex so far, but let me try it out ! thank you for your answer!